# Android: Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23'

Tags: android, gradle, google-api, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Today am getting this error

```
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' 
in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\binil.s\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23-1' 
(Expected 'C:\Users\binil.s\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23')
Already observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' in 
'C:\Users\binil.s\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23'.
 Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\binil.s\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23-1'
```

i tried  to downgrade the **buildToolsVersion** to "22.0.0", but no use

am using some libarires called **PagestripLibrary**,**Wheel**,**SocialAuthAnrdoid**, all  **buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"**
When i try to sync the project am geeting this error, Also i tried clean and sync but no use.
can anyone please tell me a solution for this

Comment: did you find a solutions?

Comment: post your gradle file code

Answer (score 1):

Just delete 'C:\Users\binil.s\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23-1'.

It work for me.